# Can I edit jpg/gif/png files in a text editor?

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg

Is there a rhyme or reason to the jpg file?  What is it?

I am looking at opening a jpg file in the basic text editor and wanting to make artistic adjustments using only the text editor.  I mean; no visualizers except to view the finished product.  No GUI.

So I open a jpg in text editor.  I have a feeling my default encoding isn't right, but I don't know.  This is a question asked because I am feeling artsy, not because I have a goal for work or something serious.

Comment: This sounds like the realm of artistic experimentation.  The worst that could happen is that you corrupt that copy of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot *practically* do this. Pretty much any random change you make to the contents of an image file will "break" the file, or some part of it. All three image formats are *compressed,* which means that the data in the file is not obviously related to the image you see on your screen, because the "raw" (say, RGB) image data has been poked, prodded, squeezed, and molded so that it can be stored using fewer bytes.

Yes, there are both rhyme and reason to the image formats. If you're curious, I suggest reading about the formats. If you're lazy and curious, click these Wikipedia links and start reading:

- [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)
- [GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF)
- [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)

Comment: what does that mean.  don't judge me.